# Specifying network settings during SLES 11 auto installation

Tags: networking, sles, sles11, autoyast

I'm setting up an autoinst.xml file for auto-installing SLES 11.  I get prompted for the various interface settings per below, but they don't seem to stick once the server reboots.  I don't think I have the xml defined correctly.  I'm hoping someone has experience with this.

```
<ask-list>
  <ask>
    <path>networking,dns,hostname</path>
    <question>Enter Hostname (server name)</question>
    <stage>initial</stage>
    <default>merkin</default>
  </ask>
  <ask>
    <path>networking,interfaces,interface,0,device</path>
    <question>Enter the primary ethernet device:</question>
    <stage>initial</stage>
    <default>eth0</default>
  </ask>
  <ask>
    <path>networking,interfaces,interface,0,ipaddr</path>
    <question>Enter the primary IP Address:</question>
    <stage>initial</stage>
    </ask>
  <ask>
    <path>networking,interfaces,interface,0,netmask</path>
    <question>Enter the Netmask Address:</question>
    <stage>initial</stage>
  </ask>
  <ask>
    <path>networking,routing,routes,route,0,gateway</path>
    <question>Enter the primary Gateway Address:</question>
    <stage>initial</stage>
  </ask>
</ask-list>
```

The first one for hostname seems to be sticking just fine, but the rest do not.  As an alternative, is there a way to stop the autoinstall at the section where you configure the network devices so that the user can take over?  I was able to show the partition proposal, but not sure how to do the same with the networking setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That autoinst.xml won't setup the persistent configuration.  There is an interface stanza that needs to be used.  The easiest way to create a autoinst.xml file is to build one box the way you want it and at the end select the "clone".  This will create the XML file in root's home dir.  Take that and modify additional settings for different machines.  Or use either the command line or GUI YAST and there is an auto install creator (if you installed it).

In the advanced installation guide look for the XML pieces for networking and for interface those are the keywords.

Comment: Yeah, copying a cloned autoinst.xml file and editing the NIC section seems to be the best solution for our needs.  Thanks.